# Mist crashing on startup UNCAUGHT EXCEPTION TypeError

Tags: mist, exceptions

I'm running the Ethereum wallet Mist in Ubuntu but it crashes on start up with this message

```
[2017-10-01 13:45:59.552] [INFO] EthereumNode - Start node using /home/oscar/.config/Mist/binaries/Geth/unpacked/geth

[2017-10-01 13:45:59.649] [ERROR] main - UNCAUGHT EXCEPTION TypeError: Cannot read property 'message' of null
    at Socket.proc.stdout.on.data (/opt/Mist/resources/app.asar/modules/ethereumNode.js:428:46)
    at emitOne (events.js:96:13)
    at Socket.emit (events.js:191:7)
    at readableAddChunk (_stream_readable.js:178:18)
    at Socket.Readable.push (_stream_readable.js:136:10)
    at Pipe.onread (net.js:560:20)
```

It was working fine yesterday but now I can't open it at all.

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same problem. That seemed to be because my port `30303` is not free, (as Mist runs a geth node itself).

If you're using Mac or Linux try this to see if the port is occuped:

`$ netstat -vanp tcp | grep 30303`

Comment: How would I kill the process occupying that port in the terminal? Thanks for the response :)